# Ionic spread content evenly over <ion-select-option>

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm creating an ionic select and in that select an item has a 3 values (strength, weakness, armor i.e.)
I want those three values to spread evenly over the ion-select-option but I can't seem to figure out how.

I experimented with various css and html options and this was my latest (failed) experiment.

```
            <ion-select class="simple-select" placeholder="Select One"
                interface="action-sheet">
                <ion-select-option *ngFor="let knight of knights" class="ion-text-wrap">
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label  slot="start">{{knight.strength}}</ion-label>
                    <ion-label>{{knight.weakness}}</ion-label>
                    <ion-label  slot="end">PPknight.armor}}</ion-label>
                </ion-item>
                </ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with [Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), either with CSS or by using [Angular's Flex Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxLayout-API) directives.

(These are rough examples, may need to tweak things)
CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

FlexLayout:

```
<ion-item fxLayout="row">
  <ion-label fxFlex>{{knight.strength}}</ion-label>
  <ion-label fxFlex>{{knight.weakness}}</ion-label>
  <ion-label fxFlex>PPknight.armor}}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```